# Does Excellent free modeling software exist?

Tags: model, modeling, visio

My friends are in a class that is requiring class diagram modeling.
We have access (legit) to Enterprise Arch but we all really hate it.

And Visio isn't meant for class modeling (at least in our opinion).

Is there a good free solution for class diagram modeling?

Thanks!

Comment: I've got a client that loves loves loves EA.  Personally I'd rather beat my brains out on the desk than use it.  (Which actually is a pretty good analogy for using EA...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also try [NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/). Works on Windows and Linux via Mono.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) is pretty good for diagramming, but I prefer tools specifically designed for UML such as [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) or the [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) [UML editor](http://uml.netbeans.org/) (although if you aren't using the rest of the NetBeans IDE, that's probably overkill).

EDIT: Apparently, the NetBeans UML Editor is no longer available in version 6.8 of the IDE.b

Answer (score 0):

If as part of the course you also need to do some programming and plan to use the Eclipse IDE, one good option would be to use one of the UML tools for eclipse : http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2-Tool-Compatibility

You can also check some links to open-source UML tools here: http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml-tools#open

However, right now my favourite tool is MagicDraw. If your class is part of a university degree, your instructor can contact MagicDraw and asked for temporary licenses for the course

Answer (score 0):

Try ARIS Express (http://www.ariscommunity.com/aris-express). It supports process models, data models, organisational charts, just to name a few. And it is free-of-charge having PDF export and MS Office integration (just copy your Express model and paste it into powerpoint).

Answer (score -1):

You should check [Star UML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/).  It's open source and quite capable.

Quote from their web:

> StarUML is an open source project to
>   develop fast, flexible, extensible,
>   featureful, and freely-available
>   UML/MDA platform running on Win32
>   platform. The goal of the StarUML
>   project is to build a software
>   modeling tool and also platform that
>   is a compelling replacement of
>   commercial UML tools such as Rational
>   Rose, Together and so on.